# LaTeX: Search keywords in file

Tags: latex

Can you use LaTeX to read in a file and search for key words? How would you do this?

I currently have code that reads a file and counts the number of lines. I was thinking that during each line read I could parse the line for specific words or tags. Can this be done?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{FileLines}
\newboolean{RestFile}
\newcommand{\FileLine}{}
\newread\File

\newcommand{\CountLinesInFile}[2]
{
  \setboolean{RestFile}{true}
  \setcounter{FileLines}{0}

  \openin\File=#1
  \whiledo{\boolean{RestFile}}
  {
    \ReadNextLine{\File}
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{RestFile}}{
    \stepcounter{FileLines}
    }{}
  }
  \closein\File
}

\newcommand{\ReadNextLine}[1]{
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{RestFile}}{
   \read#1 to \FileLine
   \ifeof#1\setboolean{RestFile}{false}
   \else % if last line already is read, EOF appears here
   \fi
  }{}
}

\begin{document}

\CountLinesInFile{textfile.txt}

Lines in file: \arabic{FileLines}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a thought, why not just use `\index` to mark keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could probably be done, but I wouldn't recommend it. TeX has a lot of constraints and idiosyncracies that make it suboptimal for general-purpose programming.

Using a general-purpose programming language like [Python](https://www.python.org/), [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), [Perl](https://www.perl.org/) or [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) would make the task a *lot* easier.

I'm specifically including Lua here because it was chosen as the *embedded scripting language* for [luaTeX](http://www.luatex.org/), the next generation of pdfTeX. With luaTex it is possible to *embed* Lua code in your TeX documents. It also exposes the internals of the TeX engine to Lua, which opens a whole world of possibilities for package writers.